# Howto set number to last run in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

What do I need to do that my saved run -configurations get numbers so that I can call them directly. I dont want to mess-around with cursor up and down. 
In the following screenshot there is a "1" for run configuration (blue background) but I do not know how it came there and what do I have to search for in IntellijDoc to add numbers like 2 to other configurations. :-)[image]

Comment: Related feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-69968

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible yet, what I do, is rename the configurations with a number at the beginning, i.e. `2. Test All` so I can take advantage of the search feature of the run dialog for achieving almost what you want to do. In this way you are going to type a bit more, but you are not going to need to use the mouse :)

[image: enumerated configurations] [image: filtered configuration]

Comment: Seems a good workaround. Unfortunately, I need to press enter after the number.